# opengl help on lenovo think pad t61

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I received a Lenovo think pad t61 the other day and installed Xubuntu 12.04 onto it. Last night I was able to run minecraft after installing bumblebee. Then I tried to see if Gary's mod would work and it wasn't able to run so I made some changes to drivers and now neither minecraft or Gary's mod works.

I tried to replicate what I did with bumblebee to solve the problem, but minecraft still does not run.

What I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get everything working by removing all drivers using

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
```

I was then able to install bumblebee with the instructions on the bumblebee page.
I had to use the one for 13.10 not 12.04 though. But I'm just glad it works.